# How to remove text decoration from accordions?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

Ive got an accordion but want to remove the text decoration from a: Hover from the panel headers, but its pretty nested. (about six layers deep)
How to do the styling for that particular element?
I'm a bit rusty with doing CSS for nested elements...
cheers.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-offset-2">

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Website
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Website Details.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Author
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Author Details. 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Credits
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Thanks to... 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you wanting to remove hover on the `<a>` tags such as Website, Author and Credits?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.panel-title a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-offset-2">

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Website
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Website Details.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Author
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Author Details. 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Credits
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Thanks to... 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to remove `text-decoration` on `hover` from `a` in headers:

```
h4 a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Altough depending on your CSS code you might have to use a selector with more specificity. If that's the case we would need to see your css code.